# How to add java function to owl prolog

Tags: java, owl, ontology

Unfortunately I am quite new to the world of ontologies and owl but I need to work on a piece of code which rely heavily on owl.
I am experiencing some problems trying to use a java function into owl. The situation is the following:

```
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="&jpg;product">
  <dhus:identifier rdf:parseType="Literal">
  <![CDATA[
     fn:tokenize(name (.), '\.')[1]
  ]]>
  </dhus:identifier>

<img:descriptor rdf:parseType="Literal" xmlns:img="&img;">
    <![CDATA[
         declare namespace utils="java:com.example.jpg.JpgUtils";
    ]]>
     <img:collection xmlns:img="&img;">
        <img:raster name="preview">
           <img:source>{ utils:acquireImageName(drb:path(.)) }</img:source>
        </img:raster>
    </img:collection>
</img:descriptor>
```

I am trying to pass the path to a jpg image to use as a preview using java code but I keep getting the `[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.` error.

Does  anyone know how to properly obtain the file path?

Comment: Is this the full content of the file? The error means the file does not start with valid XML. It's not got to any of the OWL stuff yet.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I pasted only this part of the file because this the one causing problems. If I remove the `<![CDATA[ ...  ]]>` and `{ utils:acquireImageName(drb:path(.)) }` in the `img:descriptor`, and fill the source tag with a valid path it does work properly. @Ignazio

Comment: The problem is at the very beginning of the file - check that there are no spaces or any other characters before the XML header